# Can we re-direct to our application if an external url is hit

Tags: html, go

I am using go-gin and its html template rendering engine but this question is generic. My application has a login page at https://localhost:8080/login. I use a third-party url in my application which re-directs me to another url. (eg:https://example.com). How can I force redirect to `https://localhost:8080/login` if `https://example.com` is hit?

Comment: Not sure this is a `go` problem. I would suggest you edit your `/etc/hosts` file if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: hosts itself will probably not work because you can't redirect ports. He could configure a local proxy to redirect example.com:80 to localhost:8080

Answer (score 1, accepted):

External URLs (links to a site from outside your server) can not be redirected to localhost.

1. You have to use your server IP instead of `https://localhost:8080` or map example.com to your localhost. [Mapping from your domain to your localhost](https://superuser.com/questions/559623/i-have-a-domain-name-that-i-want-to-redirect-to-my-local-server-how-do-i-do-thi)
2. Update DNS records for example.com
3. Inside your go-gin application set router to redirect to /login by `HTTP referer` or some other way.